# Javascript add comments dynamically into sources code

Tags: javascript, html, comments

I am trying to make a training website.

What I would like to do is when a page loads I want to add comments dynamically so when the user views source they will see the right comments. So I can make sure they only see comments about what I am trying to teach.

The problem I am having is that I think the browser is ignoring the added dynamically added comments so you never see them.

Any help would be great.

Comment: How are you displaying the code you want to demo? In the page source?

Comment: Check this link for example - you can manipulate comments with native DOM functions http://help.dottoro.com/ljmjwtik.php

Comment: can you share your code that currently isn't working? Else this is a "do my work/solve my problem/fix this for me" situation and risks becoming flagged